# How do I make HTML output work when using the customizer?

Tags: html, theme-customizer

[image]

How do I make HTML code that is written in the customizer output properly? I need a line break to appear where it has been placed but I am not to get it to output properly.

Comment: I'd suggest removing the line break and limit the tagline width via CSS, if the width is correct (less) then it will auto-wrap to the next line.

Answer (score 0):

Add an `&nbsp;` between the words You, Can and Trust. 
So :

```
Expert House Cleaning Service You&nbsp;Can&nbsp;Trust
```